# Weird error after implementing jquery function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I get the following error if I implement the following jQuery (for pop up footers)

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var open = false;
        $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {
            if(open === false) {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
                open = true;
            } else {
                $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
                $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
                open = false;
            }
        });     
    });
```

Error in wordpresss

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE in D:\Hosting\12006171\html\wp-content\themes\html5blank-master\functions.php on line 12

Comment: Why there is a "$" here : `function($)` ? (Edit : thanks for the answers)

Comment: @Franck http://api.jquery.com/ready/ - Aliasing the jQuery Namespace

Comment: Is that jquery function posted within a PHP block?

Comment: @Franck It is a way of renaming your jQuery variable, you can put whatever you want there and within that document.ready it will === `jQuery`. The error you are receiving is because of a `PHP` issue, not jQuery though

Comment: the jquery is indeed posted in the function.php

Comment: i would love to use this jquery but i seem to have trouble with jqueries in general.. it would be great if i could beat this error...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing $ in.

i.e.

```
function($) {
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton').click(function () {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
            open = true;
        } else {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
            open = false;
        }
    });     
}($);
```

Comment: Thx, but i tried the code and i still get the same error. do you mean i have to use a seperate code for $?

Comment: The error is possibly in your PHP code then. Have you checked whether this code runs as standalone html and javascript?

Comment: thanks! that was the problem indeed. but it is not working yet haha :P